# Ideal Solution structure with client side templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

What is the ideal solution structure for Client side templates with ASP.NET MVC ?

Would client side template definition code sit under View folder ? If so, should these files be ascx or cshtml ? What is the difference between the two ?

If I would like to use JSONResult to and from the View, should I still have View Model ? Can I just create anonymous types and convert to JSON ?

Comment: Yes, you can create an anonymous type and serialize that as the JSON response. As for your other questions, there is no "right" way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use client side templates I always use anonymous types returned as JSON. Also I use straight html files since there's no need for Razor or ASP.Net and I place them in a sub folder under /Content/ somewhere.